# Why BinaryGap incorrect for trailing_zeroes (with n =6 and n=328)

Tags: java

I Find longest sequence of zeros in binary representation of an integer but result incorrect on app.codility.com with n = 6 and n =328

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNCez.jpg

public int solution(int N) {

```
    Integer result = 1;
    StringBuilder modNumber = new StringBuilder();
    while (result > 0) {
        result = n / 2;
        modNumber.append(n % 2 + "");
        n = result;
    }

    int length = modNumber.length();
    String modString = modNumber.toString();
    Integer binaryGap = 0;
    List<Integer> lstResult = new ArrayList<>();
    Boolean isBinaryGap = false;
    if (modString.charAt(0) == '0') {
        binaryGap = 0;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            char c = modString.charAt(i);
            if (c == '0') {
                binaryGap += 1;
                isBinaryGap = true;
            } else {
                isBinaryGap = false;
            }
            if(!isBinaryGap) {
                lstResult.add(binaryGap);
                binaryGap = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int max=0;
    if(!lstResult.isEmpty()) {
     max = lstResult.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();

    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: What an insanely complicated way of going about the task.  Strings?  Lists? Streams?  All you need is a little arithmetic, a couple of counters, and a sprinkling of logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part:

```
    if (modString.charAt(0) == '0') {
        binaryGap = 0;
    } else {
```

I suspect your intention is to handle the case of the input being zero (so why not do that right off the bat, using the original value of `N`?), but you get many false positives because **your technique for forming the string places the bits in order from least-significant to most-significant**.  The least-significant bit is zero for *every* even number, and you therefore report a gap of 0 for all of them, but the only even number for which that's the correct result is 0.

I'm sure that with that information you could fix your code to produce the correct results, but the problem would not even have arisen if you had chosen a simpler approach.  For example, how about scanning the binary representation just once, keeping track of the current and maximum gap lengths as you go?  You already perform the needed scan, but instead of just computing the result directly, you go through all that mess of building and then analyzing a string representation.  Simpler code leaves less room for bugs, and when they arise, they are usually easier to spot.